# How can two Internet gateways be aggregated to achiever faster data rate than just one?

Tags: windows, networking, router, internet, gateway

I have two Verizon LTE Home Internet gateways.  Each delivers 50Mpbs down.
When I connect by Ethernet to a single Eero router, I don't get faster than 50Mpbs.

Is there some router or Windows app that will re-assemble the TCP/IP packets to achieve near 100 Mbps?

I assume Verizon tower throttles link to each gateway to just 50Mpbs, which may allow each next packet to go through the other link, and re-assemble at my end at ~100Mbps.

I need some router or Windows software that will aggregate the simultaneous Ethernet streams from each Gateway.

I have spoken with Verizon tech support, but they have no answers.

Comment: So you want (wan) link aggregation, which has been standardized into 802.3ad. Dont expect to see a download of say a 5GB file suddently peak at 100mbit, it will still be 50mbit. Download 2 (or more) 5GB files and you'll start making use of the aggregated bandwith and see peaks of almost nearly 100mbit. Also bear in mind, link aggregation adds overhead and you'll have to buy a router or switch that can handle it.

Comment: But if I have two Verizon gateways, each a 50Mbps pipe to the tower, and have something at the Windows end that aggregates, then it should be at least feasible to get near 100Mbps, yes?   Verizon tower obviously has at least 100Mbps bandwidth to their backbone, since separately they support 50 for each gateway.  Would be grand if Verizon gateways could daisy chain for aggregation.